# Sql server query to join two tables to get desired result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table **Customer-items** and **Available-locations** i need to get the location where all items in customer-items are available.

**Customer-items**

```
ItemID    ItemName
   1        item1      
   2        item2 
   3        item3
```

**Available-locations**

```
LocationID    ItemID      AvailableForPickup
   20           1             1
   20           2             1
   20           3             0
   21           1             1
   21           2             1
   21           3             1
```

on simple inner join e.g

```
 SELECT * FROM Customer-items
 INNER JOIN Available-locations
 ON Customer-items.ItemID = Available-locations.ItemsID AND AvailableForPicup = 1
```

this will exclude item 3 from Available-locations for LocationID 20 but return other two items for locationID 20 and all items for location 21.

i need to get the result set like; to exclude all items for location if any of item is not available.

**Available-locations_CustomerItems**

```
LocationID    ItemID      AvailableForPickup
   21           1             1
   21           2             1
   21           3             1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM Customer-items
INNER JOIN Available-locations
ON Customer-items.ItemID = Available-locations.ItemsID AND locationId
NOT IN (select locationID FROM Available-locations WHERE AvailableForPicup = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT B.ITEMID
    ,B.LOCATIONID
    ,B.AVAILABLEFORPICKUP
FROM #A A
RIGHT JOIN #B B ON A.ITEMID = B.ITEMID
WHERE B.AVAILABLEFORPICKUP= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `NOT IN` in following:

```
 SELECT l.* 
 FROM [Customer-items] AS i 
 INNER JOIN [Available-locations] AS l ON i.ItemID = l.ItemID
 WHERE l.LocationID NOT IN (SELECT LocationID FROM [Available-locations] WHERE AvailableForPicup = 0)
```

*Note that `-` is not available in tables names. You have to use brackets `[]` on table names like `[customer-items]`. Also use alias names on tables to make It more readable.*

**OUTPUT**

```
LocationId  ItemId  AvailableForPickup
21          1       1
21          2       1
21          3       1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Customer-items
join Available-locations
on Customer-items.ItemID = Available-locations.ItemsID
where Available-locations.LocationID in 
(select LocationID from Available-locations where AvailableForPickup = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. It's working fine with SQL Server 2012.

```
DECLARE @Customer_Items TABLE (ItemsID int,ItemName VARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @Available_Locations TABLE (LocationID int,ItemsID int,AvailableForPickup int)
INSERT INTO @Customer_Items (ItemsID,ItemName)
VALUES
(1,'item1'),
(2,'item2'),
(3,'item3')
INSERT @Available_Locations
(LocationID,ItemsID,    AvailableForPickup)
VALUES
(20,1,1),
(20,2,1),
(20,3,0),
(21,1,1),
(21,2,1),
(21,3,1)

SELECT LocationID,al.ItemsID,AvailableForPickup FROM @Customer_Items ci
 INNER JOIN @Available_Locations al
 ON ci.ItemsID = al.ItemsID AND al.AvailableForPickup = 1
 WHERE al.LocationID NOT IN (SELECT al2.LocationID FROM @Available_Locations al2 WHERE al2.AvailableForPickup =0)
```